# What's the linux shell program to control local Tor (change identity, etc)? Looks like 'top'

Tags: linux

What's the linux shell program to control local Tor (change identity, see connections, etc)?

AFAIR it looks like 'top'.

Can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `arm` (packet name on Debian is `tor-arm`). There is also `nyx` which is supposed to replace `arm` at some point. Never tried it myself though.

Comment: nyx is the same as arm. The software was renamed.